# from single column file to multi column file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file like this:

```
azg 
1234567890
asgz
1234367890
aztyu
1234377890
ast
1234367899
asgassfa
1134367890
```

and I want to create an output to look like this:

```
did          dialer-label

1234567890   azg
1234367890   asgz
1234377890   aztyu
1234367899   ast
1134367890   asgassfa
```

Ok, i got the output that i wanted using:

```
  printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "Dialer-Label" ,"DID" ,"PBX-Label" ,"Status"
  tac checklist.txt | paste - -  | tac | column -t
}
```

Now i would like to add 1 more column with data from a .csv file.
In that .csv file i have a column with numbers and a lot more columns with arguments of that numbers. I need to match the number from the did column that i managed to set earlier with the number from the csv and have an output with an argument from that .csv

at this point i have:

```
Dialer-Label    ,DID    ,PBX-Label  ,Status
LABEL1        2223338112
LABEL2        2223335689
LABEL3        2223330299
LABEL4        2223335786
LABEL5        2223335734
```

and i need to match the numbers from column "DID" with the numbers from this csv and in the column "PBX-Label" i need to have data from column C from the csv [file](https://easyupload.io/uwxg9m)

Comment: This question is not specifically related to Ubuntu. It is a question about text-processing that might better fit on https://stackoverflow.com/ I suggest to add a specification of the output format. A solution for your example case where all numbers have the same length might not work as you expect for different input. `awk` might be a suitable tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste - -` and make use of `tac` to change the order.

```
{
  printf '%s\t%s\n\n' "did" "dialer-label"
  tac file | paste - -  | tac
}
```

Optionally pipe to `| column -et` to make it nicely aligned.

Output:

```
did         dialer-label

1234567890  azg
1234367890  asgz
1234377890  aztyu
1234367899  ast
1134367890  asgassfa
```

Comment: Thank you.
It worked with:
{
  printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "Dialer-Label" ,"DID" ,"PBX-Label" ,"Status"
  tac checklist.txt | paste - -  | tac | column -t
}

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk, as follows:

- at the beginning, print a header
- for odd-numbered lines, store the label
- otherwise print the line and label

ex.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {printf "%-12s%s\n\n", "did", "dialer-label"} 
  NR%2 {label = $0; next} 
  {printf "%-12d%s\n", $0, label}
' file
did         dialer-label

1234567890  azg
1234367890  asgz
1234377890  aztyu
1234367899  ast
1134367890  asgassfa
```

If you don't care about the alignment (or don't mind piping through `column` after), then with sed:

```
printf '%s\n' dialer-label did | sed -n -e 1G -e 'h;n;G;s/\n/\t/;p' - file
did     dialer-label

1234567890      azg
1234367890      asgz
1234377890      aztyu
1234367899      ast
1134367890      asgassfa
```